Can some one review whats wrong with my ArrayFormula?
The formula below works for finding the lowest amount attached to the adjacent column.
=ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(E53:E79="L",F53:F97)))

It finds the search term "L" (for this example) with no problem)
It then finds the figure next to it with no issue but it's the lowest figure not the highest.
Could anyone please advise how I make it so it searches for the highest amount in column F?
I am only just learning Excel so I apologize if this is obvious
edit... as pointed out this was a google sheets formula
the original excel formula is {=MAX(IF(A1:A6="L",F53:F97))}
I didn't realize that the change to google sheets would alter the formula is this why its not working?
edit number 2>>>
I realized because I was was working with negative numbers I needed to use the below formula....
=ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(A3:A9="A",B3:B9)))
though the number was the largest negative number it was when using the MAX search finding the smallest negative number not the greatest
thanks to any one that read.

In order to workout a formula, it would help to provide us a sample of test data as markdown table. You can use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Also showcase us your ideal expected output for the provided test data. Here's one example question to get a general idea on how the question can be framed and all...
